# Start Docker silently on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have installed Docker Edge `18.06.01-ce` on Microsoft Windows 10 with Fall Creators Update.

I want to find a way to configure Docker silently - from for example command console. Unfortunately, I can't use Docker features without Docker daemon running in the background.

Normally I would open `Docker for Windows.exe`- it does manage Hyper-V machine `MobyLinuxVM`, creates network switches etc. The problem is that this application is running in tray and has GUI.

Is there any way to start this application from command console and wait until it will configure everyting (until Docker will work correctly)? I have already tried creating manually new machine and starting Docker service, but it does not work - I suspect that I need to map new machine somehow to new console windows (`docker-machine env`?).